# How to properly strip HTML tags dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this type of question has been asked before, which is how I came up with my regular expression in the first place, but my coding doesn't seem to be working.

I'm combining 2 things, firstly I'm trying to restrict a multiline textbox to 6000 characters and have this work on key up, which it does nicely. However, as part of this I also want to strip out HTML tags BEFORE checking the length, which is the bit that's not working. My code is below:

```
function TruncateNotes(text) {
    var notesfield = document.getElementById(text.id);
    //strip html tags such as < and > out of the text before checking length
    stripHTML(text);

    var maxlength = 6000;

    if (notesfield.value.length > maxlength) {
        notesfield.focus();
        notesfield.value = text.value.substring(0, maxlength);
        notesfield.scrolltop = notesfield.scrollHeight;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function stripHTML(text) {
    var notesfield = document.getElementById(text.id);
    notesfield.value.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
}
```

My feeling is that's something to do with the regular expression as I'm not very good with those. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sidenote: Before you think you're good enough to do proper encoding, try your hand at this: http://escape.alf.nu/ It nicely points out how incredibly hard it is to make a secure escaping of anything in HTML/JS and co.

Comment: I appreciate the additional info. However, for my purpose I simply need to stop users from getting the 'potentiialy danger...' error. The users are very unlikely to be injecting malicious code, but I don't want to remove html validation for the page just in case. As such I've really only got to remove the '<' character (which I've now added to my code) as well as full tags like <img>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript '.replace' does not *modify* the original string, it *returns* a string with the values replaced. This means you'll have to assign it back to notesfield.value after the operation:

```
notesfield.value = notesfield.value.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. My javascript isn't that great as you can see. Thanks!